# How to tag whole ViewSet in drf_yasg?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, drf-yasg

I have the following ViewSet:

```py
class AuthorViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Author.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AuthorSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.AllowAny]

    # note that no methods are overridden
```

I want `drf_yasg` to generate custom schema such that all action methods will be tagged as `Authors`.

The documentation says that my options are to either decorate each method by declaring it and using `@swagger_auto_schema` like so:

```py
class AuthorViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    # ...
    @swagger_auto_schema(tags=["Authors"])
    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().list(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Or use Django's `@method_decorator` like so:

```py
@method_decorator(name="list", decorator=swagger_auto_schema(tags=["Authors"]))
class AuthorViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    # ...
```

Both options require tedious repetition which I would like to avoid.

I've also tried to implement my own decorator:

```py
def decorate_viewset_methods(names, decorator):
    if names == "__all__":
        names = [
            "create",
            "retrieve",
            "update",
            "partial_update",
            "destroy",
            "list",
        ]

    def decorate(cls):
        for name in names:
            method = getattr(cls, name)
            setattr(cls, name, decorator(method))
        return cls

    return decorate
```

But it didn't quite work out.

So my question is how can I decorate all action methods at once?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I ended up using something like this:

first creating a custom auto schema

```
class CustomAutoSchema(SwaggerAutoSchema):

    def get_tags(self, operation_keys=None):
        tags = self.overrides.get('tags', None) or getattr(self.view, 'my_tags', [])
        if not tags:
            tags = [operation_keys[0]]

        return tags
```

in your settings file add:

```
SWAGGER_SETTINGS = {"DEFAULT_AUTO_SCHEMA_CLASS":"path.to.CustomAutoSchema"}
```

and in your View:

```
class AuthorViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Author.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AuthorSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.AllowAny]
    my_tags = ["Authors"]
```

Comment: How can I make it work with function views?

Comment: Can we use tuples here instead of list? `tags = [operation_keys[0]]`